# extract information from a file in unix using shell script

Tags: shell, unix

I have a below file which containing some data

```html
name:Mark
age:23
salary:100
```

I want to read only name, age and assign to a variable in shell script

How I can achieve this thing

I am able to real all file data by using below script not a particular data

```html
#!/bin/bash

file="/home/to/person.txt" 

val=$(cat "$file")

echo $val
```

please suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than running multiple `grep`s or `bash` loops, you could just run a single `read` that reads the output of a single invocation of `awk`:

```
read age salary name <<< $(awk -F: '/^age/{a=$2} /^salary/{s=$2} /^name/{n=$2} END{print a,s,n}' file)
```

**Results**

```
echo $age
23
echo $salary
100
echo $name
Mark
```

If the `awk` script sees an age, it sets `a` to the age. If it sees a salary , it sets `s` to the salary. If it sees a name, it sets `n` to the name. At the end of the input file, it outputs what it has seen for the `read` command to read.

Answer (score 1):

Using `grep` :  `\K` is part of `perl` regex. It acts as assertion and checks if text supplied left to it is present or not. IF present prints as per regex ignoring the text left to it.

```
name=$(grep -oP 'name:\K.*' person.txt)
age=$(grep -oP 'age:\K.*' person.txt)
salary=$(grep -oP 'salary:\K.*' person.txt)
```

Or using `awk` one liner ,this may break if the line containing extra `:` .

```
declare $(awk '{sub(/:/,"=")}1' person.txt )
```

Will result in following result:

```
sh-4.1$ echo $name
Mark
sh-4.1$ echo $age
23
sh-4.1$ echo $salary
100
```

Comment: What does `K` do in `name:\K.*`

Answer (score 0):

You could try this

if your data is in a file: `data.txt`

```
name:vijay
age:23
salary:100
```

then you could use a script like this

```
#!/bin/bash

# read will read a line until it hits a record separator i.e. newline, at which
# point it will return true, and store the line in variable $REPLY
while read 
do
    if [[ $REPLY =~ ^name:.* || $REPLY =~ ^age:.* ]]
    then
        eval ${REPLY%:*}=${REPLY#*:} # strip  suffix and prefix 
    fi
done < data.txt # read data.txt from STDIN into the while loop

echo $name
echo $age
```

output

```
vijay
23
```

Answer (score 0):

well if you can store data in json or other similar formate it will be very easy to access complex data
data.json

```
{
"name":"vijay",
"salary":"100",
"age": 23
}
```

then you can use jq to parse json and get data easily

```
jq -r '.name' data.json
vijay
```

Comment: Huh? The question didn't even mention JSON.